# Calling a delegate method in dispatch_async

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I've implemented a simple delegate pattern and I need to call delegate methods in the main queue. This is the code that perform this call:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    self.delegate?.readerDidCompleteDownload(self, data: tempData)
}
```

but I can't compile because of this error

```
Could not find member: readerDidCompleteDownload:
```

The method is implemented in the delegate and the protocol correctly defines it

```
@objc protocol DBDataReaderDelegate{
    func readerDidCompleteDownload(reader: DBDataReader, data:String[])
    
    @optional func readerDidFailDownload(reader: DBDataReader)
}
```

If I call this method outside the `dispatch_async` it works correctly.

What I'm doing wrong?!

### Edit

I'm calling this method in NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate function... I report here the full code just to add more information to this question:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession!, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask!, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL!){
    
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)
    var error:NSError
    let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    
    if let JSONObj:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSDictionary {
        var tempData:String[] = String[]()
        
        if let shots = JSONObj["shots"] as? NSDictionary[]{
            
            for (index, element) in enumerate(shots){
                
                if let title:String = element["title"] as? String{
                    tempData += title
                }
            }
            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.delegate?.readerDidCompleteDownload(self, data: tempData)
            }
        }
    }else{
        delegate?.readerDidFailDownload?(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
„The type of this function is () -> (), or “a function that has no parameters, 
 and returns Void.” Functions that don’t specify a return value always 
 return Void, which is equivalent to an empty tuple in Swift, shown as ().” 

 Apple Inc. „The Swift Programming Language”. iBooks
```

Because delegate is optional type and can be nil, and every function or method in Swift must return value, for example Void!, (), you just need to add tuple `()` at the end of dispatch_async

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    self.delegate?.readerDidCompleteDownload(self, data: tempData)
    ()
}
```

Comment: I doesn't work. I get this error: 
`Invalid use of '()' to call a value of non function type '()'`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DXM4sRdY - pase it to playground and see that everything is fine

Comment: Sorry man I've added the parenthesis just after the function call. Yep! It works... But I really understand why. Returning "void" isn't just as saying return "nothing" ?

Comment: „The type of this function is () -> (), or “a function that has no parameters, and returns Void.” Functions that don’t specify a return value always return Void, which is equivalent to an empty tuple in Swift, shown as ().”

Apple Inc. „The Swift Programming Language”. iBooks.

Comment: Damn... I completely missed this paragraph :P

Comment: Actually it's because single expression closures are inferred to return the type of that expression - which in your case is an Optional because of chaining. The added () is essentially a no-op, but suffices as an extra expression to switch off the 'single expression closure' behaviour.

Comment: You could replace () with a plain old `return` instead to verify this. Which style becomes most prevalent in swift world has yet to become clear, I'm slightly in the return camp for clarity reasons.

Answer (score 1):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
    self.delegate?.readerDidCompleteDownload(self, data: tempData)
}
```

Without `() -> Void in`, Swift infers the type of the closure. The inferred result comes from "[optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_312)" `readerDidCompleteDownload`, so it is `Void?`. That makes the inferred closure type `() -> Void?` (optional Void) which is not the same as what `dispatch_block_t` is: `() -> Void` (non-optional Void).

This could use some syntactic sugar in Swift.